# How to set value of an input tag in casperJs

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have input element as shown :

`<input type="text" class="bg-white" id="couponCode" value="">`

How can i set/fill its value using casperJs

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using `casper.sendKeys('selector', value);`

http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#sendkeys

Comment: I've been searching for this answer for an hour or more. Thank you very much.

Comment: is the focus of the cursor stays there @Srikanth Malyala?

Comment: But what to do , if id  is not given for that input ? @Srikant Malyala

Comment: You can select it by a class or by some attribute, e.g.  ('.some-btn')

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different methods available for accomplishing this task.

You should use [`casper.sendKeys()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#sendkeys) unless you need to perform a more complex operation.

---

#### [`casper.sendKeys()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#sendkeys):

If you would like to set the value from the **CasperJS environment**, and the `input` element **is optionally** inside a `form` element, then you can use `casper.sendKeys()`:

```
casper.sendKeys('#couponCode', 'Hello, world!');
```

#### [`casper.fill()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill):

If you would like to set the value from the **CasperJS environment**, and the `input` element **is** inside a `form` element, and **includes** a `name` attribute, then you can use `casper.fill()`:

```
casper.fill('#form', {
  couponCode: 'Hello, world!', // #form [name="couponCode"]
});
```

#### [`casper.fillSelectors()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors):

If you would like to set the value from the **CasperJS environment**, and the `input` element **is** inside a `form` element, and you would like to reference the `input` element using a CSS3 selector, then you can use `casper.fillSelectors()`:

```
casper.fillSelectors('#form', {
  '#couponCode': 'Hello, world!', // #form #couponCode
});
```

#### [`casper.fillLabels()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#filllabels):

If you would like to set the value from the **CasperJS environment**, and the `input` element **is** inside a `form` element, and **includes** an associated `label` element with text, then you can use `casper.fillLabels()`:

```
casper.fillLabels('#form', {
  couponCode: 'Hello, world!', // #form label[text()="couponCode"] input
});
```

#### [`casper.fillXPath()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillxpath):

If you would like to set the value from the **CasperJS environment**, and the `input` element **is** inside a `form` element, and you would like to reference the `input` element using an XPath selector, then you can use `casper.fillXPath()`:

```
casper.fillXPath('#form', {
  '//*[@id="couponCode"]': 'Hello, world!', // #form #couponCode
});
```

#### [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

If you would like to set the value from the **Page DOM environment**, and the `input` element **is optionally** inside a `form` element, then you can use `casper.evaluate()`:

```
casper.evaluate(function () {
  document.getElementById('couponCode').value = 'Hello, world!';
});
```

> **Note:** Similarly to `evaluate()`, you can also use: [`evaluateOrDie()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluateordie), [`thenEvaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenevaluate), or [`thenOpenAndEvaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenopenandevaluate) (if you would like to accomplish two or more operations at once in relation to the steps being executed).